# Layout "atualizando" após começar a digitar

Tags: ios, swift, swift-3

Estou com um bug meio inusitado, estou criando uma tela de login onde tenho dois `UITextField` e um  `UIButton` para fazer o login.

O problema é, ao subir o teclado o botão que está na `safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottom` com uma distancia de -15. A idea é que quando o teclado aparecer o botão ficar com espaçamento de 15 do teclado e ao começar a digitar o botão ficar em cima do teclado até o mesmo desaparecer. Porém ao começar a digitar o `UIButton` volta para posição inicial e não tenho a menor ideia do motivo disso, sendo que não chama nenhuma função para isso.

Login View onde tenho os observer do teclado

```
// MARK: - Notification Keyboard
    func addKeyboardNotifications() {
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(keyboardShowNotification:)),
            name: UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification,
            object: nil
        )
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)),
            name: UIResponder.keyboardDidHideNotification,
            object: nil
        )
    }
    
    func removeKeyboardNotification() {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(
            self,
            name: UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification,
            object: nil
        )
        
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(
            self,
            name: UIResponder.keyboardDidHideNotification,
            object: nil
        )
    }
    
    // MARK: - Keyboard height
    @objc
    private func keyboardWillShow(keyboardShowNotification notification: Notification) {
        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
           let keyboardRectangle = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? CGRect {
            if !isKeyboardShowing {
                isKeyboardShowing = true
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                    self.continueButton.frame = CGRect(
                        x: self.continueButton.frame.origin.x,
                        y: self.continueButton.frame.origin.y - keyboardRectangle.height,
                        width: self.continueButton.frame.size.width,
                        height: self.continueButton.frame.size.height)
                    self.layoutSubviews()
                })
            }
        }
    }
    
    @objc
    func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
           let keyboardRectangle = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect {
            if isKeyboardShowing {
                isKeyboardShowing = false
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                    self.continueButton.frame = CGRect(
                        x: self.continueButton.frame.origin.x,
                        y: self.continueButton.frame.origin.y + keyboardRectangle.height,
                        width: self.continueButton.frame.size.width,
                        height: self.continueButton.frame.size.height)
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

Constraint do Botão

```
private func setupConstraintsContinueButton() {
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            continueButton.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: passwordTextField.bottomAnchor, constant: 15),
            continueButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -15),
            continueButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 32),
            continueButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -32),
            continueButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
        ])
    }
```

O que já tentei:

1. Trocar o `userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]` por `userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification]`
2. Verificar as constraints no layout inspector (que aparece normal)
3. Verifiquei o frame( e por algum motivo que não sei ele volta para posição inicial).
4. Colocar `self.layoutSubviews()`  após fazer a animação.

tem o exemplo do que está ocorrendo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bom se alguém souber onde estou errando e puder me explicar agradeço.

PS: por algum motivo o gif não está mostrando, mas após o teclado sumir o botão "Cai" pra baixo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa @andre-firmo. Podemos evitar manipular diretamente o `frame` e focar apenas em trabalhar com Constraints. Também não precisamos de todos Observers dependendo do que se pretende. Nesse caso acredito que você consiga resolver com algumas modificações:

1. Manipule diretamente o `bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -32)`, com isso você só precisa trabalhar diretamente com a altura que o Observer do Keyboard pega.
2. Atualize esse mesmo constraint ao fechar/esconder o keyboard.

O código abaixo deve resolver.

```
import UIKit

extension UIView {
    func updateConstraint(attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute, constant: CGFloat) -> Void {
        if let constraint = constraints
            .filter({ $0.firstAttribute == attribute })
            .first {
            
            constraint.constant = constant
            layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private lazy var emailField: UITextField = {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.textContentType = .emailAddress
        textField.keyboardType = .emailAddress
        textField.autocapitalizationType = .none
        textField.placeholder = "E-mail"
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        return textField
    }()

    private lazy var passwordField: UITextField = {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.isSecureTextEntry = true
        textField.placeholder = "••••••••••••"
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        return textField
    }()

    private lazy var loginButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        button.setTitle("Entrar", for: .normal)
        button.tintColor = .white
        button.backgroundColor = .black
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(hidesKeyboard), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        return button
    }()
}

extension ViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)),
            name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification,
            object: nil
        )
        
        layoutViewConstraints()
    }
    
    private func layoutViewConstraints() {
        view.addSubview(emailField)
        view.addSubview(passwordField)
        view.addSubview(loginButton)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            emailField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 88),
            emailField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            emailField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            emailField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            
            passwordField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emailField.bottomAnchor, constant: 32),
            passwordField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            passwordField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            passwordField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            
            loginButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -32),
            loginButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            loginButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            loginButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            loginButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -32)
        ])
    }
}

extension ViewController {
    @objc private func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {
        let userInfo = notification.userInfo! as NSDictionary
        let keyboardFrame = userInfo.value(forKey: UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey) as! NSValue
        let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
        let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height + 32
        
        view.updateConstraint(attribute: .bottom, constant: -keyboardHeight)
    }

    @objc private func hidesKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
        view.updateConstraint(attribute: .bottom, constant: -32)
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @AmarildoLucas , funcionou, e vlw por me explicar!